# Does each pull request create a separate remote branch?

Tags: github, pull-request, ghstack

I'm not sure if this is specific to the repo (PyTorch) I'm working with or if it applies generally, but it seems every time I submit a pull request, a remote branch on the repo is created. Is this supposed to happen and if so, what is the logic behind it?

If you have your own local branch and keep making commits and submitting pull requests, why can't it all go on the same remote branch?

Comment: Can you post your exact commands and the results you are seeing?

Comment: Pull Requests do not create remote branches, they use existing ones. If you want to add commits to an existing PR you commit to the same local branch as the existing PR and `git push` that branch up to the remote. Something else is happening here. Could you show your PR process, please?

Comment: @Schwern I will get back on this. I don't use `git push` directly for pytorch development. There's this internal tool called `ghstack` https://github.com/ezyang/ghstack that has the pushing and pull requesting embedded within it. I just found this link and currently going through it right now, and I think it's actually this tool that's creating the additional remote branches (I had thought it was a github thing). I'm trying to understand the reason behind it.

Comment: In that link, I think the relevant section is under "Design Constraints". This tool seems to create a separate pull request for EACH commit in the stack

Comment: I don't know the tool you're using, but creating a new branch for each PR is not a bad practice. Just delete the branch once you've merged the PR if you don't want those branches to stick around afterwards. In my own workflow I create a new branch every time I start any bit of work, and delete it once that work is merged in. Branches are cheap, you don't need to hesitate creating them. I like naming them `dev.brief-description-of-the-task` to make it easier to figure out what each branch is later.

Comment: @user5965026 "*This tool will push and create pull requests for each commit on the stack.*" Question answered, I suppose. I've seen this single-commit-branch process used before by tools such as Gerrit. I do not recommend it. While it is certainly simpler to only have to make one commit per task, it is also far less useful. Being able to divide a task up into multiple commits is a powerful development tool; ghstack takes that away.

Comment: Worth pointing out: "pull requests" (as seen on GitHub) are not part of *Git*. They are a GitHub add-on. Other hosting sites also add on something similar, but they all have slightly different quirks and some don't call them "pull requests" (e.g., GitLab call them "merge requests" instead). So any details you learn for GitHub PRs are likely to be specific to GitHub.

Comment: @Schwern Wait, I'm not sure how that answers the question about each pull request creating a new remote branch. How does that answer it? (I did get confirmation with the developer of the tool that that's indeed what it does however, but curious how you were able to infer that from that italicized statement)

Comment: @user5965026 Github pull requests don't create branches. You're using a tool (ghstack) which does. ghstack says you "*prepare a series of commits on top of master, then run ghstack. This tool will push and create pull requests for each commit on the stack.*" For example, if you have three local commits on master and you run `ghstack` it will make a remote branch *for each commit* and a PR *for each commit*. This is all done by ghstack, not Git nor Github. This is not how one normally uses Git nor Github; it's a process specific to the `ghstack` tool. I do not recommend this process.

Comment: @user5965026 The normal Github PR process is to make a local branch off master, make some commits on that branch, push that branch to Github, and then make a PR from that remote branch. You make and push the branch, then create a PR from that branch. See [Collaborating with pull requests](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests).

Answer (score 1):

Github Pull Requests do not create branches. You're using a tool, [`ghstack`](https://github.com/ezyang/ghstack), which does.

The normal Github PR process is to make a local branch off master, make some commits on that branch, push that branch to Github, and then make a PR from that remote branch. You make the branch, you push it, you open a PR for it. See [Collaborating with pull requests](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests) for more information on the normal PR process. This is often referred to as the [Feature Branch Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow).

`ghstack` has its own process.

> Prepare a series of commits on top of master, then run ghstack. This tool will push and create pull requests for each commit on the stack.

For example, if you have three local commits on master and you run `ghstack` it will make a remote branch for each commit and a PR for each commit. This is all done by ghstack, not Git nor Github. This is not how one normally uses Git nor Github; it's a process specific to the ghstack tool.

The advantage of single-commit branches is it makes branch management simpler. The disadvantage is it loses the ability to break work down into a set of distinct but related changes; that's what a branch is, distinct but related changes.

ghstack seems to be replacing the concept of a branch with a "stack" of commits.

*In my opinion* single-commit branches make the code more difficult to review and it makes the code more difficult to understand later. The commits will either be large and difficult to review, or they will be small and difficult to understand how they relate.